# TypeError: imwrite() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save jpg image with quality 80 by opencv. Here is the python script I tried:

```
cv2.imwrite(isdocker.DOCKER_PREFIX + IM.path + IM.name, IM.data, [(int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),80)])
```

It pops up with an error 'TypeError: imwrite() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given'. I know a similar post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629370/python-error-imwrite-takes-at-most-3-arguments-4-given). But I think its different issue. I have read the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#ga292d81be8d76901bff7988d18d2b42ac) from opencv and it seems they have changed something. Please help me.

Additional Information:**Python 3.9.7** (default, May 19 2022, 00:53:30) [GCC 9.3.0] on linux Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. >>> import cv2 >>> **cv2.**version** '4.5.5'**

Answer (score 3):

You almost have it. The third parameter is the codec's *compression parameters*, and it is given as a list of integers (not a list of tuples). Like this:

```
cv2.imwrite(imagePath, inputImage, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 80])
```

Comment: Still have same problem. This time i have tried as per your suggesion

'cv2.imwrite(isdocker.DOCKER_PREFIX + IM.path + IM.name, IM.data, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY,80])'

Comment: So the error must be somewhere else. Check your image `path`, it must be a `string`. Check the image you are trying to write, it must be a `numpy array`. Trying the code you posted, Python returns a _"function returned NULL without setting an error"_ System Error. Fixing the compression parameters fixes this particular error and successfully writes an image.

Comment: Make sure to concatenate the extension _.jpg_ at the end of your path.

Comment: i just removed the part  [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY,80], and its working now. So definitely its the issue with cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY

Answer (score 0):

If you use yolov5, this problem can be explained.

In /utils/general.py , you can find something like:

```
def imwrite(path,im):
    # do something
cv2.imread , cv2.imwrite ,cv2.imshow = imread , imwrite , imshow
```

You can just modify it or delete it to specify the jpeg quality

Comment: This answer doesn't address what the asker was looking for. Further it complicates matters by introducing an unrelated topic/tool (yolov5)

Comment: OK, more specifically speaking. I encountered the same problem: 
"imwrite() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given", and after removing the third parameter  [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY,100], it worked. Finally I found out that the yolov5 I used overrides cv2.imwrite (with only two parameters). So I just provide a possible solution if the asker also uses yolov5 (maybe he thought yolov5 is totally unrelated just like I did, so he didn't mention it).

Comment: I see, this would make sense if it is indeed what the OP is using. The docs for cv2 v4.5.5 indicate that a 3rd parameter is accepted https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce.

Comment: Yes, I am using a docker container which implements the yolov5. The base image for the container is "nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:21.11-tf2-py3". Although I have installed opencv (4.5.5) but this does not allow to add image quality. However, I think this answer might be helpful.